# Generic function with implicit parameter

Tags: scala, generics

I have a situation where I am trying to create a generic function which should be able to take any instance of a class which specifies a certain implicit value in its companion object.  I have replicated my problem below:

```
// Mocking up the library I am working with
trait Formatter[A] {
    def output(o: A): String
    def input(s: String): A
}


// Some models
trait Human

case class Child(name: String) extends Human
object Child {
    implicit val f: Formatter[Child] = new Formatter[Child] {
        override def output(c: Child): String = { ... }
        override def input(s: String): Child = { ... }
    }
}

case class Teen(name: String) extends Human
object Teen {
    implicit val f: Formatter[Teen] = new Formatter[Teen] {
        override def output(t: Teen): String = { ... }
        override def input(s: String): Teen = { ... }
    }
}


// The generic function
def gen[A <: Human](a: A)(implicit format: Formatter[A]) = {
    // Do something with a formatter...
}
```

---

This all works fine, I can pass an instance of a `Child` or a `Teen` to my `gen` function:

```
gen(Child("Peter"))
gen(Teen("Emily"))
```

---

What I am having trouble with is that at run time I only know that the instance I am passing will be a subtype of a `Human`:

```
// Example of unknown subtype
val human: Human = Random.nextBoolean match {
    case true => Child("Peter")
    case false => Teen("Emily")
}

gen(human)  // Error: Could not find implicit value for parameter format...
```

I understand that the error is because `Human` has no companion object and therefore it has no implementation of a `Formatter`.

How can I add a constraint to `Human` that says "anything extending Human will implement a new Formatter" ?

Comment: Not sure so only leaving a comment.
But could you create a companion object for Human which has an implicit def which pattern matches on the Human and returns the appropriate formatter.
If the implicit doesn't work you could always have a method in the Human companion object which you manually call and pass that into your funtion rather than implicits.
I think the problem with this would be that Human needs 'to know about' your subclasses. I don't think this is that bad since Human is sealed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scenario fails because you should implement a Formatter[Human]. I think that what you want is that all the Human should be able to have this format "capability" instead.

At this point you have two options, one is to include in the Human trait a method for formatting (this implementation could be in the object if you want it static) or try a dsl approach where you will create a class with the responsibility to provide humans a new capability: "format".

The first approach could be something like this:

```
trait Human { def format:String }

case class Child(name: String) extends Human {
  import Child._
  override def format = Child.staticFormat(this)
}

object Child {
  def staticFormat(c: Child): String = s"Child(${c.name})"
}
```

However I think "format" shouldn't be in the contract "Human" so I prefer the second approach:

```
trait Human

case class Child(name: String) extends Human

case class Teen(name: String) extends Human

import scala.language.implicitConversions

class HumanFormatter(human: Human) {
  def format: String = human match {
    case c: Child => s"Child(${c.name})"
    case t: Teen => s"Teen(${t.name})"
  }
}

object HumanDsl {
  implicit def humanFormatter(human: Human): HumanFormatter = new HumanFormatter(human) 
}

object Test extends App {
  def human: Human = Random.nextBoolean match {
    case true => Child("Peter")
    case false => Teen("Emily")
  }

  import HumanDsl._

  for(i <- 1 to 10) println(human.format)
}
```

What are the differences between both solutions?
In the first one you force all the new Human classes to implement a format method so you can assure that your code will work always. But at the same time... you are adding a Human a method that from my point of view is not necessary, I think a case class should have only the information needed and if you need to format/parse that class then is better to add this functionality just when needed (dsl approach).

In the other hand, with dsl you should update the formatter anytime a new Human class is created. So it means that the human.format method above will fail if a new Human class is created (you can always match _ to do a default behaviour or raise a custom error).

I think is a matter of design, I hope this would help you a little bit.

---

### Edited:

just like a comment showed the Human trait could be sealed to ensure that the HumanFormatter pattern match doesn't compile if some class is not covered.

Comment: You could make Human sealed.
That way HumanFormatter will not compile unless you implement format for new instances of Human that arise.

Comment: @A Spoty Spot that's what I was looking for... thanks I will update!!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need implicits for this.
Just make your subclasses point to the implementation directly:

```
trait Human[+A <: Human] {
 def formatter: Formatter[A]
}

case class Child(name: String) extends Human[Child] {
 def formatter = Child.f
}

// etc
def gen[A <: Human](a: A) {
   // do something with a.formatter 
}
```

Of course, `Formatter` needs to be covariant in `A` too. Otherwise, all bets are off: you simply cannot do what you want - there is nothing useful `gen` could do with it without knowing the specific type anyway.

If specifics of the concrete type are not needed in gen, you can still use implicits by enumerating them explicitly like this (but I don't really see why you would want that):

```
 object Human {
    implicit def formatter(h: Human): Formatter[_] = h match {
      case Child(_) => Child.f
      case Teen(_) => Teen.f
    }
 }

 gen(h: Human)(implicit f: Formatter[_]) { ... }
```

Like I said, this does not seem very useful though, so not sure why you want want this over the above approach.

Comment: The `Formatter` in my real code is for marshalling and unmarshalling JSON objects.  Its actually the `play.api.libs.Json.{Writes, Reads}`.  What I am trying to do is create generic function which can take any model and send back a Json response (which would use the Formatter).  Perhaps I am just going about the problem wrong.

Comment: I think either of the two approaches above should work for this (you can use the existential type in the first approach as well rather than making it covariant).

Comment: Like I said in my answer I think that you want a dsl approach, some kind of marshall/unmarshall specific class that is applied when needed, leaving Human case classes just with busines code (marshall, format, etc. shouldn't be in a case class from my opinion).